# Query triangulation

Tags: database, networking

I have the following usage pattern that I'm wondering if there's a known way to deal with it.

Let's say I have a website where a user can build a query to run it against the remote database. The remote database is secure and the user will not have access to it. Therefore, the query, what will be something like: `SELECT * FROM myTable` will be sent to our web server, and our web server will query the remote DB on another server, receive the results and pass them back in the HTTP response. So, the flow is:

- Location1 (Europe): User/browser submits HTTP POST containing the SQL Query.

  - Location2 (US): HTTP Server receives request, runs SQL against database:

    - Location3 (Asia): Database runs query, returns data
  - Location2 (US): HTTP Server receives SQL resultset back. Sends response.
- Location1 (Europe): User/browser receives the data back in the rendered webpage.

Supposing that I don't have control of the three locations, we can see that there may be a lot of data transfer latency if the size of the resultset is large. I was wondering if there is any way to do something like the following instead, and if so how it could be done:

- Location1 (Europe): User/browser submits HTTP POST containing the SQL Query.

  - Location2 (US): HTTP Server receives request, sends back QueryID immediately, runs SQL against database, asynchronously.

    - Location3 (Asia) Database runs query
- Location1 (Europe): User/browser receives response from database. (How? It cannot pull directly from DB)

---

To summarize, if we imagine the resultset is 50MB in size, in the first case, the 50MB would go from:

```
Asia (DB) -> US (Server) -> Europe (Client)
```

and in the second case it would go from:

```
Asia (DB) -> Europe (Client)
```

Comment: To what extent could the solution be language/vendor specific?  What if an (avoidable imo) cause of the the latency comes from the type conversion on web server when receiving the data back from the db?  Would you consider an alternative data flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decouple authentication with authorization to allow more flexible connections between all three entities: Browser, HTTP server, and DB.

To make your second example work you could do:

- The HTTP server (US) submits asynchroneously the query to the DB (Asia) and requests a auth token for it.
- The HTTP server (US) sends the auth token back to the browser (Europe), while the query is now running.
- The browser (Europe) now initiates a second HTTP call against the DB (Asia) using the auth token, and maybe the queryID as well.
- The DB will probably need to implement a simple token auth protocol. It should:

  - Authenticate the incoming auth token.
  - Retrieve the session.
  - Start streaming the query result set back to the caller.

For the DB server, there are plenty of out-of-the-box slim docker images you can spin in seconds that implement authorization server and that can listen to the browser using nginx.

As you can see the architecture can be worked out. However, the DB server in Asia will need to be revamped to implement some kind of token authorization. The simplest and widespread strategy is to use OAuth2, that is all the rage nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for this. A couple questions on this: (1) this approach would of course only work on a DB where we have access to modify the server, correct? For example, using a managed server like Snowflake/BigQuery would be a non starter, right? (2) You mention using a slim nginx/oauth2 image, are there any you can point out that might be a good starting point? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I tend to think this is not a plug-and-play solution in terms of the DB, since an extra service will need to run on top of the database itself. However, nowadays, these services could already be part of the offering. If you are working with BigQuery I would start looking at their offering; maybe it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @TheImpalers answer:

How about add another table to your remote DB that is just for retrieving query  result?

When client asks the backend service for database query, the backend service will generate a UUID or other secure token and tell the DB to run the query and store it under the given UUID. The backend service also returns the UUID to the client who can then retrieve the associated data from the DB directly.

Comment: thanks, could you give an example though of how the privileges would work? Is the table-name itself just the guid and the client has access to that single table, or...?

Comment: I would design a single table with the UUID as they key and the query result as another table. You can always make the UUID longer if you have a security concern.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

```
Europe (Client) -> US (Server) -> Asia (Server) -> Asia (DB)
```

Open a HTTP server in Asia (if not don't have access to same DC/server - rent a different one), then re-direct request from HTTP US -> HTTP Asia, which will connect to local DB & stream the response.

Redirect can either be a public one (302) or a private proxying over VPN if you care about latency & have such possibility.

Frontend talking to DB directly is not a very good pattern, because you can't do any middleware operations that you'll need in a long term (breaking changes, analytics, authorization, redirects, rate-limiting, scalability...)

If your SQL is very heavy & you can't do sync requests with long-lasting TCP connections, set up streaming over websocket server (also in Asia).